# c# sharepoint how to set a FIELD Value of SPListItem with FIELD Value from other SPListItem?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, spfield

I want to upload mulitple Documents (Files) into a Sharepoint FOLDER.
During the "ItemAdded" Event I want to 'copy' the FIELDS of the Parent Folder 
(SPListItem) to the current (uploaded) Item.

When I check for the FIELDS of the current Item, all of them are
already there.

But HOW can I copy every FIELD VALUE from the Folder Item to the
uploaded Item?

I dont know how to READ OUT the Values of the FIELDS from "ItemSource"

```
SPList currentList = properties.List;
SPDocumentLibrary oDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)currentList;
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.Items;
int AnzahlItems = collListItems.Count;
SPFieldCollection currentListFieldItems = currentList.Fields;
int AnzahlFields = currentListFieldItems.Count;
// ---------------------------------
// Get the current Item in the List
// ---------------------------------
SPListItem currentItem = currentList.Items[AnzahlItems - 1];
SPFieldCollection currentItemFields = currentItem.Fields;
int currentItemFieldsAnzahl = currentItemFields.Count;

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// For every FIELD from Source Item ADD FIELD to Target Item
// -----------------------------------------------------------
               for (int i = 0; i < AnzahlFields; i++)
               {

                   SPField NeuesFeld = currentListFieldItems[i];
                   String FeldInternalName = currentListFieldItems[i].InternalName;
                   String FeldName = currentListFieldItems[i].Title;
                   NeuesFeld.Type = currentListFieldItems[i].Type;
                   NeuesFeld.Required = currentListFieldItems[i].Required;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInEditForm = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInDisplayForm = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInListSettings = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInNewForm = true;
                   NeuesFeld.ShowInViewForms = true;

                   // ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
                   // Folder Item 1 --> Felder anhängen ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
                   // ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                   if (currentItem.Fields.ContainsField(FeldInternalName))
                   {
                    // The FIELD is already existing at the Target Item

                   }
                   else
                   {
                     // The FIELD is not existing at Target Item, will be added
                       currentItem.Fields.Add(NeuesFeld);
                   }

               } // end for

               // ----------------------------
               // Save Changes at Item
               // ----------------------------
               currentItem.Update();
```

This code above is not working, it gives always the message "The FIELD is already existing"
How can I read out the VALUE of the FIELD ?? 
I am frustrated there is no method to read out the Value of a FIELD ??
Please help...

Steffen

Answer (score 4):

this is useful case, and I always try it   source from [Get And Set Value By Field Internal Name](http://apicollection.wikia.com/wiki/Get_And_Set_Value_By_Field_Internal_Name)

```
void UpdateSPListItem(SPListItem item, Model pageItem)
    {
        SetValueInternalName(item, "ArticleByLine", pageItem.ArticleByLine);

        SetValueInternalName(item, "Comments", pageItem.Comments);

    }
    void SetValueInternalName(SPListItem item, string fieldInternalName, string value)
    {
        SPField field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldInternalName);
        item[field.Id] = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to take value from that field. Each sharepoint field type, has it's own class representation in c#. When you have string value, it's easy but when you have relation you need to use SPFieldLookup, etc.

When you have string, you can write something like that:

```
string stringFieldValue = sourceItem[internalFieldName] != null ? currentItem[internalFieldName].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

and then use

```
folderItem[internalFieldName] = stringFieldValue;
```

internalFieldName -> this is internal name of field, you can check it by go to the list and sort by this field, and you will have it name in querystring (url)

[How to get lookup value from SpListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325725/get-the-lookup-field-value-for-a-list-item-in-sharepoint-2010-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you please write the code more in "IF THEN ELSE" Syntax?
I dont understand the "?" and ":" syntax.... :)

Comment: string stringFieldValue = string.Empty;
if(sourceItem[internalFieldName] != null)
{
stringFieldValue = currentItem[internalFieldName].ToString()'
}
else
{
stringFieldValue = string.Empty;
}